Can’t upgrade Ubuntu due to etckeeper
The operating system fails to make the proper updates:
/etc/etckeeper/unclean.d/README: 1: Files: not found
/etc/etckeeper/unclean.d/README: 2: uncommitted: not found
/etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/README: 1: Files: not found
/etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/README: 2: etc.: not found
/etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/README: 3: uncommitted: not found
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Pre-Invoke 'if [ -x /usr/bin/etckeeper ]; then etckeeper pre-install; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code

For completeness, I inform that the files listed as not found are instead in place, this their content only:
1. /etc/etckeeper/unclean.d/README:
Files in this directory are used to test if the working copy has uncommitted changes.
2. /etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/README
Files in this directory are run before packages are installed, upgraded, etc. This is mostly used for sanity checks, ie, does /etc have any uncommitted changes?
Can you please assist me to fix the bug?
Thank you in advance.

Ubuntu Linux 22.04.4

It does find the files you think it doesn't. It complains somehow about the first word in each line of that files, I can't tell you the reason. Seems to be a bug. You will have to file a bug report against the package etckeeper, we are not the developers of the package and can't solve the bug for you.

As a workaround, you can temporarily apt remove etckeeper then perform the update, then reinstall with apt install etckeeper  The issue here is that etckeeper tracks changes to the /etc directory so if you do as I suggest you'll lose changes every time you update with it removed.  If it's mandatory that you track changes, you cannot update until you do as mock765 suggested.

You could probably try to comment out tthe lines in that files or even move these files (this are readme files, they should not be needed for the proper funcion of the software) somewhere else and try if it works then. There are more readme files in the other subdirectories of /etc/etckeeper which may lead to similar problems. You should really file a bug report.
